# Start a new interval when a button is pressed again

Tags: javascript, countdown

My query is fairly simple. I was able to make a countdown script, so when a button is clicked the countdown begins; however, if we keep clicking the button it just adds another countdown and mess the original one too. I tried to clear the interval, but not sure what does not make it run. When I press Start the countdown begins, but if you click on it again, well you can try it yourself. I am also not able to figure out how a stop button can end the interval timer and I have tried cleartInterval(); as well.

```js
$("#startClock").click( function(){
     var counter = document.getElementById('minutes').value;
   setInterval(function() {
     counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
         span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = counter;
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
        span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = "";
       }
     },  1000);


});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.1'></script>
Minutes
<select id="minutes">
  <option value="60">1</option>
  <option value="120">2</option>
  <option value="180">3</option>
  <option value="240">4</option>
  <option value="300">5</option>
  </select>
<button id=startClock >Start</button>
<button id=stopClock >Stop</button> <br/> 
<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: "I have tried cleartInterval(); " — That's what you need to do, but you haven't shown your attempt to use it, so we can't tell what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var clickTimer;

$("#startClock").click( function(){
     if (clickTimer) {
        clearInterval(clickTimer);
     }
     var counter = document.getElementById('minutes').value;
     clickTimer = setInterval(function() {
     counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
         span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = counter;
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
        span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = "";
       }
     },  1000);


});
```

EDIT

```
$("#stopClock").click( function(){
 if (clickTimer) {
    clearInterval(clickTimer);
    clickTimer = undefined;
 }
});
```

Comment: That was quick.. Thanks!

Comment: Also, is it possible for me to pause the timer with Stop or Pause button?

Comment: That did pause the timer.. Thanks!